# New line does not appear in 'cases' environment

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

$$(v_n) \begin{cases} u_0=\frac{1}{2} \\ r=7 \end{cases}$$

\end{document}
```

Result :

[image]

I'm trying to make a multiline equation but when I use the code above it does not appear on multiple lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code a full compilable example that shows your problem (starting from `\documentclass` , ending in `\end{document}` and containing all the code and packages needed just to show clearly your problem -without not needed packages and extra code that has nothing to do with your problem-)... This is called a MWE (Minimal Working Example)  and is almost a mast in order to get a fast and accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just modified my question to be more understandable.

Comment: Welcome... I wanted to see there what is the `spaces` environment and how to use it... But you miss-spelled the `cases`... corrected.

Comment: @GaëtanBallèvreRio The excellent user koleygr have written an important reason. You have not put any package for write your formula.

Comment: For historical reasons, LaTeX defines a `\cases` command, which is used here and it's just by chance you get no error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two observations:

- The double sign (`$$...$$`) method of initiating and terminating display-math material is deprecated in LaTeX documents. You should use `\[...\]` instead.
- It is very important to know your preamble. The `cases` environment is not defined by the LaTeX kernel. It's necessary to load either the `amsmath` package or the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) in order to be able to use the `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[(v_n) =\begin{cases} u_0=\frac{1}{2} \\ r=7 \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, importing the `mathtools` package solved the problem. I don't quite understand why but it's working ! Also thanks for the good practice of using `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`.

Comment: We are here to help all of us and we all have to help each other. For me this is the spirit of the TeX.SE site which is an excellent site where there are very good people. Your code can work very well using other packages, but it is also important that you insert next time a complete small example that reproduces the problem and that you also read some guides. I'll send you my regards.